# Why is the text of snack displayed only one time?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code is based the project architecture-samples, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

In my mind, the UI will dispplay the text of snack with `R.string.description_hint` first, then display  the text of snack with `R.string.empty_task_message`.

But I find the only the text of snack with `R.string.empty_task_message` is displayed, how can I fix it?

**TasksFragment.kt**

```
private fun setupSnackbar() {
        view?.setupSnackbar(this, viewModel.snackbarText, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
        viewModel.setMy1()
        //Wait until UI updated
        viewModel.setMy2()       
}
```

**TasksViewModel.kt**

```
class TasksViewModel(
    private val tasksRepository: TasksRepository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {


  private val _snackbarText = MutableLiveData<Event<Int>>()
  val snackbarText: LiveData<Event<Int>> = _snackbarText

    fun setMy1(){
        _snackbarText.value=Event(R.string.description_hint)
    }

    fun setMy2(){
        _snackbarText.value=Event(R.string.empty_task_message)
    }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Snackbar.Callback. You can have List that contains your messages to be shown, a function to call to show snackbar messages with a callback added to your snackbar, and a livedata to be updated (when snackbar onDismiss is called from the callback) to trigger show snackbar message with the next message from your message list(e.g. index + 1).

[Snackbar callback doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar.Callback)